# Scala - how to not use a future in http request

Tags: scala, methods, future

I'm following this simple example for HTTP requests using the dispatch library.

[Dispatch tutorial](http://lollyrock.com/articles/scala-http-requests/)

I want to make a request without using futures. I want to wait for a response. How can I do this?

I've tried below by removing the future declaration and `oncomplete`.

Thanks

```
import dispatch._, Defaults._
import scala.util.{Success, Failure}

object DispatchTest {
    def main (args: Array[String]) {
        val svc = url("http://www.wikipedia.org/");
        val response : Future[String] = Http(svc OK as.String)

        response onComplete {
            case Success(content) => {
                println("Successful response" + content)
            }
            case Failure(t) => {
                println("An error has occurred: " + t.getMessage)
            }
        }
    }
}

import dispatch._, Defaults._
import scala.util.{Success, Failure}

object DispatchTest {
    def main (args: Array[String]) {
        val svc = url("http://www.wikipedia.org/");
        val response : String = Http(svc OK as.String)
    }
}
```

Comment: If the Dispatch API does not give you that, you could simply wait for completion using `Await.result(...)` or `Await.ready(...)` - both are found in `scala.concurrent.Await`. This is however not the best use of your threads because you're making a thread block to wait for a result.

Answer (score 3):

This should be what you need: blocks current thread until response comes back.

```
import dispatch._

object DispatchBlocking extends App {
  val q = url("http://www.scala-lang.org/")
  val r = Http(q OK as.String)()
  println(r)
}
```

Comment: ^
Yes exactly. You need to .apply() the Future.

Comment: Thanks @Michal Ostruszka. I get an error `unspecified value parameter executor` on `val r = Http(q OK as.String)()`. Also what do the empty brackets () mean? Thanks

Comment: try `val r = Http(q OK as.String) ; println( r() )` . The brackets are a speciality of Dispatch. It's a shorthand for `Await.Result(  myFuture,forever)`

Comment: Which dispatch version do you use?